# finding your position on the page from the top

Tags: jquery

When scrolling, how do I found out how far down the document I have scrolled down from the top?

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
pos = $(document).offset().top;
$('#info').html(pos);
});
```

I tried the above code, and I have replaced document with window, but still not luck.

I actually want an event to occur when the document has scrolled down x pixels, is this even the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried with `scrollTop()`?

Comment: I just tried pos = $('#header_container').scrollTop(); header_container being the first element on the page, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `document`, try `html`

This should do :

```
alert($('html').offset().top);
```

OR, with `window` try this way...even simpler!!

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: @user2909486 :  hmmm....strange..have you added the jQuery library?? try this : `$(window).scrollTop();`